# Android : On orientation change always webservice is called

Tags: android, device-orientation

When I change device orientation, I am able to change layout properly but its also load data every time from  web service. There is no need to call  web service  each time.

So please suggest.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html -- you'll need to persist state through orientation changes, including whether or not your webservice has been called, and any results.

Comment: handling life cycle methods and yours configurations will solve yours problem11

Answer (score 1):

Add this in manifest under your activity:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```